# Arcpy - deleted my entire workspace?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I've got a script which runs through some GPS data and creates several outputs (tables, shapefiles etc.).

However, when I've just run it, the folder where all the input data lies (along with most of the outputs) has just vanished without a trace. It's not even the recycling bin.

The only references to 'Delete' are deleting fields, deleting a table if it exists (*arcpy.Delete_management(gpsStreetSummary)*) and at the start deleting a GDB if it exists.

There's nothing I can find in the script to explain why it would just delete everything?? Does anyone know if there is a bug in arcpy that sometimes causes this to happen?

Comment: Delete_management deletes the file off disk not just a table.  So I guess you just nuked all the data with that one command.

Comment: So Delete_management deletes everything despite what's in the argument? Here gpsStreetSummary is just one of several files. It's worked fine before but all of a sudden I've found absolutely everything in the workspace deleted

Comment: Well it should only delete that one file then.  Maybe post more of you code?

Comment: According to the [ESRI docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000052000000), delete would only move a folder to the recycle bin even if you were doing it with that somehow. You'll need to add some detail.